# Large (> 4mb) File Attachments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API, it is possible to add file attachments to messages as described [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_post_attachments). However, since REST requests have a total size limit of 4mb this does not allow for very large attachments.

A [resumable upload session](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession) allows for larger uploads that may be referenced by reference attachments providing a download link. However, these links are obviously short-lived and we would like to clean up the files at some point.

Is there any way to create a message with persistent file attachments larger than 4mb? Thinking along the lines of a DriveItem->FileAttachment conversion here, but could not find anything on the topic. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As of [May 2017](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog#may-2017) you can use the [referenceAttachment resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/referenceattachment). This allows you to attach a `DriveItem` from the OneDrive to a `message`:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/AAMkAGE1M88AADUv0uFAAA=/attachments
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 319

{ 
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment", 
    "name": "Personal pictures", 
    "sourceUrl": "https://contoso.com/personal/mario_contoso_net/Documents/Pics", 
    "providerType": "oneDriveConsumer", 
    "permission": "Edit", 
    "isFolder": "True" 
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and reference attachment doesn't make it through to an external email address yet in sent items in O365 I see the reference attachment and can view it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post this as it's own question? Make sure you include the code and/or the HTTP traffic you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Marc, posted a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692280/send-reference-attachment-to-email-via-graph-api