# Mail with large (> 4mb) File Attachments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Similar to [Large (> 4mb) File Attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937359/large-4mb-file-attachments), I'd like to create and send emails with > 4MB file attachments through the Graph API. Using a reference attachment is not an option either.

I've asked for this on Uservoice just in case (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/14158095-graph-sdk-upload-limit-should-be-higher).

Are there any other workarounds I should try?

Comment: This isn't "similar", it is identical.  The answer is also the same, you upload the file to OneDrive and use the [referenceAttachment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/referenceattachment) functionality to add it to an email.

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur-MSFT, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Pressed 'enter' prematurely: Unfortunately, because using referenceAttachments is not an option (must be a fileAttachment), the answer to the linked question isn't helpful. The legacy Outlook API supports a 150MB limit - can the limit for the next-gen Graph API be made the same?

Comment: The limit for all Graph requests is 4MB, it is not a limit simply on mail.

Comment: Understood - then is there a plan to up that in the future? Or will there be something like the creatUploadSession for OneDrive in the graph API?

Comment: Hey Chris - We are working on enhancement to support large file attachment; we expect to have some public updates on this in a couple of months. Thanks.

Comment: @ArunV that's very helpful, I'll look forward to it!

Comment: Hi @ArunV, just checking in here - is it worth my team reverting back to the old Outlook API to get past the 4MB limit? Or are you guys close enough that we should hold off?

Comment: Running into the same problem!

Comment: @ArunV do you have an update on this? thanks!

Comment: This is being currently worked on, no ETA yet.

Comment: @ArunV any updates? This is a blocker for me (can't use OneDrive)

Answer (score -1):

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments), you have to use the **referenceAttachment resource type**.

You can also upload your files via one-drive APIs.

Let's dig inside a solution:

> 1. Create an upload session
> 2. Within that upload session, iteratively upload ranges of bytes (up to 4 MB each time) until all the bytes of the file have been uploaded,
>      and the file is attached to the specified message
> 3. Save the ID for the attachment for future access
> 4. Optional: Delete the upload session

```js
// Step 1: Create an upload session

const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const uploadSession = {
  AttachmentItem: {
    attachmentType: "file",
    name: "flower", 
    size: 3483322
  }
};

let res = await client.api('/me/messages/AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=/attachments/createUploadSession')
    .version('beta')
    .post(uploadSession);

// Response
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession",
    "uploadUrl": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('a8e8e219-4931-95c1-b73d-62626fd79c32@72aa88bf-76f0-494f-91ab-2d7cd730db47')/Messages('AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=')/AttachmentSessions('AAMkADI5MAAIT3k0tAAA=')?authtoken=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IktmYUNIUlN6bllHMmNI",
    "expirationDateTime": "2019-09-25T01:09:30.7671707Z",
    "nextExpectedRanges": [
        "0-"
    ]
}

// Step 2: Use the upload session to upload a range of bytes of the file

PUT https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('a8e8e219-4931-95c1-b73d-62626fd79c32@72aa88bf-76f0-494f-91ab-2d7cd730db47')/Messages('AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=')/AttachmentSessions('AAMkADI5MAAIT3k0tAAA=')?authtoken=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IktmYUNIUlN6bllHMmNI
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 2097152
Content-Range: bytes 0-2097151/3483322

{
  <bytes 0-2097151 of the file to be attached, in binary format>
}


// Step 3: Continue uploading byte ranges until the entire file has been uploaded

PUT https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('a8e8e219-4931-95c1-b73d-62626fd79c32@72aa88bf-76f0-494f-91ab-2d7cd730db47')/Messages('AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=')/AttachmentSessions('AAMkADI5MAAIT3k0tAAA=')?authtoken=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IktmYUNIUlN6bllHMmNI
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1386170
Content-Range: bytes 2097152-3483321/3483322

{
  <bytes 2097152-3483321 of the file to be attached, in binary format>
}


// Step 4 (optional): Get the file attachment from the message
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/api/v1.0/Users('a8e8e219-4931-95c1-b73d-62626fd79c32@72aa88bf-76f0-494f-91ab-2d7cd730db47')/Messages('AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAA=')/Attachments('AAMkADI5MAAIT3drCAAABEgAQANAqbAe7qaROhYdTnUQwXm0=')?$select=lastModifiedDateTime,name,contentType,size,isInline,contentId,contentLocation
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24539759)

Comment: Thanks for your mention, I have just added the details