# Send reference attachment to email via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Graph API has a 4MB request limit so if I want to send an email with say a 10MB attachment I can't use the `FileAttachment` type. As I understand it the recommended way to do this is with a `ReferenceAttachment` which carries a link to a file that has been uploaded to `OneDrive` (which does accept large payloads). However, when I do this I can see the `ReferenceAttachment` in Sent Items (and can download it intact) but the attachment is not present at the destination (Gmail or Outlook).

I'm calling the `beta` API using this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/USERNAME/microsoft.graph.sendMail
```

The content posted is:

```
{
  "saveToSentItems": true,
  "message": {
    "attachments": [
      {
        "sourceUrl": "https://100255-my.sharepoint.com/personal/USERNAME/Documents/sent-attachments/largefile.txt_6T7sHv5E",
        "permission": "view",
        "providerType": "oneDriveConsumer",
        "name": "largefile.txt",
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment"
      }
    ],
    "subject": "Test E-Mail",
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "me@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I ensure that the email recipient gets the attachment?

**EDIT:**
When I use `providerType: onDriveBusiness` I get a bit further. I get sent to gmail an unintelligible binary attachment (`winmail.dat` or `noname`) with the primary email and then a secondary email with a link asking me to open an account with Microsoft so that I can view the shared file. The subject of the second email is:

`USERNAME wants to share the file largefile.txt_6T7sHv5E with you`

Note that this is what happens to gmail. When I use the Outlook client on Windows connected to Exchange I don't get the attachment nor the second email. Yuk!

What a palaver! There's no way my business (Search and Rescue) will accept this API with the obvious obstacles for an email recipient! Can I reconstruct the full email as one without unintelligible binary attachments and without creating accounts on Microsoft?

Comment: Comment from @ArunV: *Thanks for reporting the issue, we'll investigate and get back. Also I wanted to share the update with you that we are working on supporting large attachments on the Graph API and plan to release the same in later part of this year.* I've copied this into here because the answer with this information was deleted by a moderator (correctly).

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAMER**: I have started writting the answer and when on the last step realized that it does not solve the problem. Decided to left it for informational purposes. It at least concludes that `/messages/{messageID}/send` endpoint is buggy too.

Reading graph API [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/beta-overview) makes me suggest next steps to achieve what you are looking for:

1. Create the message draft using `POST` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages` with payload:

   ```
   {
       "subject": "TestMessage",
       "toRecipients": [
           {
               "emailAddress":{
                   "address":"egor-mailbox@ya.ru"
               }
           }
       ],
       "body": {
           "contentType": "html",
           "content": "<b>Hello!</b>"
       }
   },
   ```

   As a response you will get the whole message structure with `id` set to something like `AQMkADAwATMwMAItMTJkYi03YjFjLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA_hRKmxc6QpJks9QJkO5R50HAP6mz4np5UJHkvaxWZjGproAAAIBDwAAAP6mz4np5UJHkvaxWZjGproAAAAUZT2jAAAA`. Lets refer to it as `{messageID}`. **NOTE**: as you can see I have passed html-typed body. This is needed because (at least in GraphAPI Explorer) graph api returns error in case you are trying to add reference attachment to message with non-html body content-type.
2. After that you can create an attachment using `POST` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{messageID}/attachments`

   ```
   {
       "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment",
       "name": "AttachmentName",
       "sourceUrl": "https://1drv.ms/u/s!ASDLKASDLASHDLASKDLJAXCXZ_DASD",
       "providerType": "oneDriveConsumer",
       "isFolder": false
   }
   ```
3. After step `2` you will see created message in your mailbox `Drafts` folder. To send it use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{messageID}/send` (=( turns out it does not work too)

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone happen to know which options there are for 'providerType' beyond OneDrive? Cannot seem to find the documentation. Wondering if it supports Azure Blob storage.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/referenceattachment?view=graph-rest-beta

The type of provider that supports an attachment of this contentType. Possible values are: other, oneDriveBusiness, oneDriveConsumer, dropbox. Optional.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is related to jar files, when i deploy the code into weblogic it was preferring weblogic gson jar.
i have added the below code to resolve the issue in weblogic.xml file
prefer-application-packages and package name like com.google.*