# Sending Email with attachments which are > 4MB

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Retrieving the token from the below code

```
var token = await GetAccessToken();
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
  new GraphServiceClient($"{graphApi}/v1.0",
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async(requestMessage) =>
    {
      requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    })
  );
```

sending Email using App permission using

```
graphServiceClient.Users[fromAddress]
  .SendMail(message, false)
  .Request()
  .PostAsync().Wait();
```

And attachments are been attached when created dynamically

```
attachments.Add(new FileAttachment
{
  ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    ContentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(getAttachmentLocation() + attach.Name),
    ContentId = attach.Name,
    ContentType = "csv/html",
    Name = attach.Name,
    IsInline = false
});
```

Now the issue is email is not been triggered when the attachment size is more than 4MB.

Could someone help me understand how to fix this issue?

Do we have anything which actually increases the threshold of this 4MB or a newer version of Graph that supports attachments > 4 MB?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937359/large-4mb-file-attachments

Comment: Don't use `.Wait()`.

Comment: I am able to save the attachmet as draft in outlook message but the issue that I am facing is mail is not been sent .Receiving delivery failure message in Inbox. How can I send attachments with >3MB and <3MB files in single message.?

Comment: looks like if the attachaments size is less than 3MB also email is not been triggered.After much research came to know that  it is due to API request length is 4MB only.How do we increase that.

Answer (score 0):

To send larger messages you have to create a draft message, and then add attachments.
If the attachment is larger than 3MB, you cannot send it with one request. Use UploadSession instead as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp